# OpenLayers - Edit Features (hide/show, change Icon)

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openstreetmap

I´m not a pro in webdevelopment, but i´m getting stuck with openlayers :-(

I want to edit some features (hide/show and/or change the icon)

But i dont know how!

What i am looking for:
how i can i access the features (maybe with the function "updateFilter")?

and what is the difference between my code, and these two examples:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/translate-features.html

some code (everything is in one script-tag):

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  });
    
    
 // Style
  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
   image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    //anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png'
    //size: [40, 40]
    // the scale factor
    scale: 0.3
   }))
  });
    
    
    
 //add a feature:
 var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([12.12,12.12], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
   type:'Point',
   Name: 'Test Feature',
   Description: 'TEST TEST',
   TESTID:0
  });   
 
   iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

  vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
    
   var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: vectorSource;
  });
  
  

  var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM();
  });
    
    /**
  * Elements that make up the popup.
  */
  var container = document.getElementById('popup');
  var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
  var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
  
  //Pan duration 
  var overlay  = new ol.Overlay({
   element: container,
   autoPan: true,
   autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 1000
   }
  });
  
  /**
   ClickHandler 
  **/
  closer.onclick = function() {
   overlay.setPosition(undefined);
   closer.blur();
   return false;
  };
  
  
  
  var centerPos = [12,12];
  

  var map = new ol.Map({
   layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
   overlays: [overlay ],
   target: document.getElementById('map'),
   view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform(centerPos, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    
    zoom: 12,
    minZoom:11,
    maxZoom:18
   })
  });
  
  // display popup on click
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
   
   var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    evt.pixel,function(feature)
    {
     return feature;
    }
   );
   
   if (feature) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    
   
    
    content.innerHTML = "<H2>" + feature.get('Name') + "</H2>" + "<br>" + feature.get('Description') + "<br>"
     + ' <button onclick="overlay.setPosition(undefined);closer.blur();return false;">Close Window</button> ';
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
   }
   else
   {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);closer.blur();return false;
   }
  });
  
  
 
  
  map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
   if (e.dragging) {$(element).popover('destroy');
        return;
       }
   var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
   var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
   map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
  });
    
    
     var updateFunc = document.getElementById('KartenZugriff');
  updateFunc.addEventListener('click', function(){updateFilter(map)});
  
  function updateFilter(map){
   
   alert("Test start");
   var features = vectorSource.getFeatures();
   
  
   
   //var testitem = vectorLayer.GetFeatureBy('SchulID',6);
   
   
   console.log(features);
   
   for (var i in features) {
    
    var feature = features[i];
    
    
    var test = ol.getFeaturebyID();
    
 
 
    
    
    if(feature.N.SchulName ==='Some Name'){
    
     console.log(feature.getID());
     console.log("deleting..");
     rasterLayer.removeFeatures(rasterLayer.getFeatureById(6));
     console.log("...deleted?");
     
  
     console.log(style.M.b);
     
     feature.setStyle(style);
     
   
     alert("end");
    }
    
    
   };
      
   
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  
   <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
     <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
     <div id="popup-content"></div>

    </div>
<button type="button" id="KartenZugriff">ACTION!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explore the documentation more.

```
const array_of_features = source.getFeatures();
const single_feature = source.getFeatureById('id');
const feature_props = single_feature.getProperties();

// update style of feature
single_feature.setStyle(new_style);

// remove feature
source.removeFeature(single_feature);
```